# Post request with superagent in React fails

Tags: javascript, php, api, reactjs

I'm trying to make a `post` request with `superagent` but it always fails. I've tried many solutions from internet, including adding multiple headers, but none of them seems to work. The code:

```
createUser () {
var email = this.refs.email.value;
Request.post('http://advacedcrm.local/api/users/create').set('Accept', 'application/json').send({email: email}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

}

I have to mention that the API is also made by me, and I put some headers there:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
```

at the very beginning of the `routes.php` file (on `Laravel 5.2`).
The API middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('options')) {
        return response('', 200)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'accept, content-type, x-xsrf-token, x-csrf-token');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

But when I post it, the error I'm receiving:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://advacedcrm.local/api/users/create. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

So I'm out of ideas, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can install superagent

```
npm install superagent --save
```

then for make post call to server

```
import request from "../../node_modules/superagent/superagent";

request
.post('http://localhost/userLogin')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
.send({ username: "username", password: "password" })
.end(function(err, res){
console.log(res.text);
});
```